# Why I can't access the servlet after the session time out?

Tags: java, session, servlets, tomcat7, servlet-filters

I have a JSP, Servlet, Hibernate application. In this application I have a very weird problem. That is, if the session got expired (in other words "time out") and when the user click on a link the page will be redirected to the index page, but after that the user is not able to log in and access the last link he clicked. I will describe it step by step in below.

1. User log into the application. Session get created.
2. He access the path **/Passport**
3. User is now idle, session get expired.
4. User come back and click on link to access **/Visa** . Since the session is now idle, user will be redirected to index page.
5. User log in.
6. Click on the link to access **/Visa** (from anywhere where the link is available)
   . The link is an  where it links to its path like

   Visa?idEmployee=1
7. Now the problem. User is redirected back to index page.

I have `Filter` to monitor whether the session is `null` and whether the required session attributes are not `null`. If the request do not fulfill the mentioned 2 conditions, the request will be sent back to the index.

The filter code is below.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package Filter;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class AuthenticationFilter_Level1 implements Filter
{

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)res;

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        Integer attribute = null;

        if(session!=null && session.getAttribute("idSubUser")!=null)
        {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);

        }
        else
        {
            //response.sendRedirect("index.html");
            RequestDispatcher dispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
            dispatch.forward(req, res);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void destroy()
    {

    }

}
```

In web.xml, I have added the filter from servlet to servlet, like below.

```
 <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter_Level1</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/RegSrvlt</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/AdminPopulateSrvlt</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/AgentPopulate</url-pattern>
......
```

Filter session timeout is configured as below.

```
<session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            1
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

So, what is happening here?

**Update**

When the above error happens, the URL actually looks like `http://localhost:8080/xxx/Visa?idEmployee=1` even though it is redirected!

**UPDATE**

I found this has no connection with the filter. Then what can make this?

Comment: Where does the session attribute idSubUser get set?  Is it possible that resolves to null, and therefore the user is being redirected to index.html?

Answer (score 1):

```
    else
    {
        if (session != null) {
            session.invalidate();
        }
        ...
```

And check the where sessions are created (i.e. public JSPs/servlets).

Comment: Instead of a forward you might try a sendRedirect.

Comment: The `forward` is actually good to include the current `HttpRequest` object. That might actually be the way to save his situation: by including the data as part of the Request, not the Session!

Comment: When Logging in, make sure to create a new Session, and set the `"idSubUser"` Session Attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause could be a problem of caching in browser :

- client browser asks for `/Visa`
- server sends `index.html` => browser caches it as it is a nice html page
- ...
- on same **browser** session, user clicks on a `/Visa` links
- without even asking anything to server, browser displays cached `index.html` page

How do confirm :

- server side, by looking the server logs to see if the page was actually requested
- client or server side by using a network spy such as [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) and look if a request is sended
- client side by emptying the cache and not the cookies

How to fix :

- try to add a header asking not to cache the page before forwarding to `index.html` - it should be possible but I do not exactly know the proper header configuration
- replace the forward to `index.html` with a redirection. That way the browser should not cache `index.html` for the `/Visa` URL

Comment: Thanks for the reply. About the `redirection`, you mean `response.sendRedirect("index.html");` ? It didnt work too!

Comment: I noticed there is no error in the filter. I printed a message whenever a redirection is requested, and when the error happens, nothing got printed!

Comment: @JustCause: you must first clean browser cache, before retrying with `sendRedirect`, to be sure it is not caused by a previous caching.